# How can i design my asp.net-oracle configuration?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, plsql, ado.net, web-config

I'm working on a asp.net project. I'm gonna use oracle db. I've started to design my database class(for connection and sql command operations). I know how i will write connection or query section and functions (i used ado.net with ms sql before and i remember that was easyer on mssql) But i have some problems about the first operations. I dont know if i need to design in web config(if i need, i dont know how to do it). And i dont know whats my connection string. There are somethings on web that i found but i couldnt get it. I'm using oracle sql developer (purple icon). I looked for something about my connection string on the tool. But i'm not used to using oracle.

Comment: What is your _main_ question ? you are mixing 3-4 questions simultaneously. Please be sure what exactly do you want and let us know what have you tried for that.

Comment: I want to use sql connection and command in my project and i dont know what should i do first.

Comment: You should not show your `connectionstring` like this, as it will be a threat. Also update your question with all your details.

Comment: Ok im gonna try for a while, and make sure what i need to. Thank u

Comment: just go step by step.what you want then go for it on google and if you dont get anything useful come back

Comment: Ok. Just can u tell me do i need to write somethink in web.config about connection? (In asp.net project, im gonna use sqlconnection and sql command)

Comment: For `web.config` file under `connectionstrings` write something like this

`<add name="OracleConn" connectionString="Data Source=yourdatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=YourUserId;Password=*****;Unicode=True;Workaround Oracle Bug 914652=true" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/>`

Comment: Ok, firstly i need to und. that keywords and why i need to use that it in web config. You make me clear that what i should to look. Thx for help

Comment: for more info look at here http://asp.net-informations.com/ado.net/asp-connection-string.htm

Comment: I don't think Oracle SQL Developer has a purple icon.

Comment: U think the developer, the gray one. But we have another here, it is purple :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 2 ways ,however first method is obsoleted not recommended to use

Method:1 Under web.config of your asp.net you can use below code

```
     <appSettings>
        <!--Development String-->
        <add key="CustomerDataConnectionString" value="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server_address)(PORT=Port_Number))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID =SessionID)));User Id=***;Password=***;"/>
    </appSettings
 //in asp.net code file access that using below way
  static string strConnectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["CustomerDataConnectionString"].ToString();
```

Method:2

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="CustomerDataConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=server_db_address;User Id=***;Password=***;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Northwind;OLEDB.NET=True" providerName="OraOLEDB.Oracle"/>
</connectionStrings>
string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CustomerDataConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

//Common code for both the method in Database layer

```
DataTable table = null;
            using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(strConnectionString))
            {
                using (OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
                    cmd.CommandText = commandName;

                    try
                    {
                        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            con.Open();

                        }

                        using (OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {
                            table = new DataTable();
                            da.Fill(table);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hi. I figured out it with solution like your sec method after searching. I had another problems about my connection string but i've handled all of it now. But we can say for here (for the guy who will come here :d) the solution is in your answers second method. -I'm on a login procedure for login which getting parameter from asp side and i have some problems on it, so maybe we'll see again under another subject :))- Thank u!